# Clear out multicast listeners in .NET

Tags: .net, network-programming, winsock

I have a problem where sometimes when I call UdpClient.JoinMulticastGroup (.NET call), I get a "system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full" exception ([details here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/d40cb95f-6b46-4597-9cd1-d7d8cc8266e1)).

Is there some SDK call where I can have it close all orphan multi-cast listeners? Or close all on a given address/port?

I think I know the cause - it occurs when our program which has a worker thread listening on the multicast port is killed a couple of times in the debugger. If I do that enough, I then get this.

My question is how can I tell it to drop resources for apps that are dead? My app is a .NET Word AddIn.

thanks - dave

Comment: Do you have an option to call DropMulticastgroup from a Dispose method or as a last resoure a destructor?